# Javascript dynamically add new Array Objects into existing Array (with keys)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an existing Javascript Array with Keys, like:

```
var myArray = new Array();
myArray.push({ "id":"A123", "pwd":"helloworld", "items":[] });
```

So the ..

```
myArray["items"] <-------- will store multi-dimension Arrays inside again.
```

.. is currently a blank room.
Then now, how do I add new multiple Arrays into this `myArray["items]` room?

Lets say I have a loop to add items (total count is dynamic then):

```
foreach(.......)
{
    var newItem = [{"itemcode": "i1001", "itemname": "apple"}];
    myArray.items.push( newItem ); // NOT WORKING
    myArray["items"] = newItem; // NOT WORKING ALSO
}
```

Simply debug like this:

```
alert( JSON.stringify( myArray ) );
```

.. and it is returning the Array Structure but the `"items"` room is blank.

So how do I dynamically add new Objects into an existing Array room, with KEY, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is `myArray` is an array, and the object which has `items` array is at index 0 so

```
myArray[0].items.push( newItem );
```

---

In your case there is no need to use an array, just use a object lik

```
var obj = {
    "id": "A123",
    "pwd": "helloworld",
    "items": []
};
obj.items.push(obj);
```